# how to format time using java with flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm getting in flex String `Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+0530 2012` so in my Java program I'm converting like this

```
try {
    String str_date = "Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+0530 2012";

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
}
```

but it gives

```
`Exception :java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+0530 2012"`
```

Comment: Why don't you send a timestamp?

Comment: if we pass like this it is correct:Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+05:30 2012   but the String is:Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+0530 2012

Answer (score 1):

@Florent's answer is good, but since that was written Java has gained new date/time packages. This is one way to do it in Java 8 and later:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

// ...

String input = "Sat Aug 4 13:10:00 GMT+0530 2012";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);
```

The `dateTime` object can then be used for date/time calculations, or rendered as a string using another formatter, or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Good answer. You need one `d` for one-digit day of month and should provude an English-speaking locale, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`. And since the string has an offset, why not parse into an `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

This formatter works:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
```